# Parse Json file with country codes with Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt

I need to parse a long json file which contains country names and ISD dialing codes. I need to get those in preferably a QVector or an array so that I can populate them in drop down menu such as QComboBox.

I tried using QJsonObject class but I am not able to parse as expected. length returns zero.

Here is my sample file.

```
[{
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "dial_code": "+93",
    "code": "AF"
  },
  {
    "name": "Aland Islands",
    "dial_code": "+358",
    "code": "AX"
  },
  {
    "name": "Albania",
    "dial_code": "+355",
    "code": "AL"
  },
  {
    "name": "Algeria",
    "dial_code": "+213",
    "code": "DZ"
  }]
```

I tried below code:

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonFile->readAll());
jsonFile->close();

if(!doc.isNull())
{
    qDebug() << "Good Json document";
}

QJsonObject jObject = doc.object();
qDebug() << "length : " << jObject.length();

QJsonObject::iterator i;
for (i = jObject.begin(); i != jObject.end(); ++i)
{
    if (i.value().isNull())
        qDebug() << i.key();
    else
        qDebug() << i.key() << i.value();
}
```

Comment: show what you tried even if it doesn't work

Comment: @eyllanesc I put the trial code

Comment: Have you used the fullpath of the file? Are you sure that QFile opened the file correctly?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes the I can see the content of the file when I do "qDebug()"

Comment: In my case length returns 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are interpreting the root object of your document as a JSON object, not an array as it is really. You should use this code:

```
QJsonArray rootArray = doc.array();
```

instead of

```
QJsonObject jObject = doc.object();
```

Then, you can iterate on the various Object contained in this array.

See [QJsonDocument::isArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#isArray) and [QJsonDocument::isObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#isObject) to test whether your are dealing with an array or an object before calling `QJsonDocument::array` or `QJsonDocument::object`

Answer (score 1):

*I have taken too much time to answer so I voted up **@epsilon**'s answer. This answer becomes a complement then.*

---

The problem is that you are handling a `QJsonArray` as a `QJsonObject`.

In fact, your data is a `QJsonArray` of `QJsonObject`s.
To be more clear, you have an array which is a list of objects.

I have written a short example to parse exactly the data format you have:

```
int main()
{
    QFile json_file("path/to/your/file.json");

    // Read the file
    if(!json_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        return -1;
    QByteArray json_raw = json_file.readAll();
    json_file.close();

    // Parse the json
    QJsonParseError json_error;
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json_raw, &json_error);
    if(json_error.error != QJsonParseError::NoError)
        return -1;

    // Parse your specific data
    QVector <QJsonObject> contents;
    if(!parseJsonCountries(doc, contents))
        return -1;

    // Display the contents
    for(const QJsonObject & item : contents)
    {
        qDebug() << item.value("name").toString() << " : " << item.value("dial_code").toString() << " : " << item.value("code").toString();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here you have the parsing function:

```
bool parseJsonCountries(const QJsonDocument & doc, QVector<QJsonObject> & contents)
{
    if(!doc.isArray())
        return false;
    QJsonArray data = doc.array();

    QJsonObject obj;
    for(QJsonValueRef item : data)
    {
        if(!item.isObject())
            return false;

        obj = item.toObject();

        if(obj.size() != 3)
            return false;

        if( ! (obj.contains("name") && obj.contains("dial_code") && obj.contains("code")) )
            return false;

        contents << obj;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have made an effort to provide you a function that stores the data in a `QVector` as you wanted it initially.

I hope it can help.